# Only run unit tests which's respective source code has changed?

Tags: java, junit, jenkins, regression

I am running unit tests and Selenium tests in our Jenkins CI server. As we all know, tests take long to run in a large project.

Is there a tool/framework for Java which could only trigger tests whose respective source code has changed? This because not every commit to SCM affects all areas of the source code...

I am using Cobertura for code coverage and Surefire for reporting.

EDIT: I found Atlassian Clover, but I am searching for a free solution.

Comment: Do _respective source code_ only contain Java classes or some other resources (e.g. XML configuration files) as well?

Comment: Does respective source code mean that you still test all the classes that are dependend on those you have changed even if they where not changed themselves?

Comment: Good question, I guess this actually depends on the tool used. I would imagine some tools run execute tests when the 1) test covered source code has changed, or 2) changed source code dependent source class has changed. Or something in between...

Comment: "Do respective source code only contain Java classes or some other resources": only Java classes

Comment: This could have other benefits beyond time taken to run tests. A system which tells you which tests are affected by a group of commits, could provide insights about unexpected coupling within your codebase. This could also serve to direct the efforts of manual exploratory testing, in areas they may not have thought to check as a result of a seemingly unrelated change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am running unit tests and Selenium tests in our Jenkins CI server.
>   As we all know, tests take long to run in a large project.

This is the problem I'd tackle. Split your project into multiple logical units (e.g. Persistence Layer, Service Layer, Web Layer) and test them individually. That way you only need to run Selenium tests when the web layer has changed and the build time per artifact grows shorter

Comment: Sure, but how does Jenkins know that service layer artifacts have changed and only those tests should be executed? Isn't the problem the same as my original question, i.e. how does Jenkins know what relevant tests to execute?

Comment: @user1340582 Nope, not if you set up seperate jenkins jobs for each maven artifact

Comment: ... but how does Jenkins know what maven artefact to execute? All source code is compiled in one go.

Comment: @user1340582 again, I am suggesting to split your project into multiple maven modules, which of course would be compiled separately

Answer (score 5):

In general you cannot reliably infer what code is covered by what test without running it, and even when you do run your tests the execution path could be different from run to run. I suspect perfect analysis like this is equivalent to [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

However you can infer what tests are likely to exercise changed code using either coverage from previous test run or imports in the test case files.

In the end, you do want to run your entire test suite, however, you are right that running tests over changed code is more important because 1. developer knows they messed up earlier and 2. if you experience a lot of changes, it makes sense to test newest revision first and go to earlier revisions only to bisect problems.

Google famously claimed `*` that their hacked code repository runs unit tests at commit time `**` and that they tweaked the test framework to determine what tests to run first. I don't know if their changes are public.

`*` video talk to conference presentation, I don't recall exact name or link

`**` strictly after commit, followed by automatic rollback if tests begin to fail

Answer (score 3):

You could try [JUnit Max](http://junitmax.com/) or [Infinitest](http://infinitest.github.io/), but they're both IDE-based.

Comment: Also, JUnitMax isn't free.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I think you're looking at this the wrong way. What would be better to look at would be breaking down your Junit tests into separate packages based off of functionality and time.

For projects like this I run sanity tests for each commit, but these tests are very limited and cover the most basic of functions and then on top of this run nightly tests to cover much more (seeing as no-one works nights, it gives a 12 hour window to test that days code).

If your entire testing suite required it (but I would be surprised if it did) you could then run a weekend test suite.

To test only altered classes would assume that these classes don't affect any other parts of your project, which could lead to errors that wouldn't be picked up unless you did comprehensive tests, or you just happened to be altering the affected area anyway.

I know this doesn't technically answer your question, but something to think over.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but it is not quite as elegant ;) I remember .NET Visual Studio having this "IntelliSense" functionality that does what I looking after.